# Move/Slide Page To Left/Right Whe User Slide Left/Rigt With Finger On Touch Device

Tags: javascript, html, touch

I wanted my webpage can change when user slide left/right using their finger on touch device (android/tablet). I found following source code that works what i need:

http://padilicious.com/code/touchevents/

But that has few limitations. It doesn't move/slide the page/element to left/right. It just change the page (href/page location). So, user don't understand whether they slide it correctly or not.

but on touch screen device like gallery you can see when user slide to left/right image move to left/right as user move the finger and it goes away left/right when user finish the slide.

i want to do something like that.

so, when user move finger my page will move with the finger too and when he remove the finger my page will go left/right with slide transition effect.

here is the sample code for page transition...

http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_trans_slide

hope that make sense..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQt](http://jqtjs.com/) to capture touch screen swipe events. After capturing these events you can easily make an application that navigates like you want. Also jQt has it's own webkit animations. And they are pretty cool.

You can also check this [Safari Web Content Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html) to capture these events yourself.

Another nice [tutorial](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents2.shtml) for detecting swipes for touch screens.

Comment: dear, in my post, i already told i can detect those touch event and it works. what i need is to slide the page/element to left/right based on the touch. though thanks for your reply.